# Ruby undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass or Loop error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

...

```
begin

  last = Folder.where(name: @folders.last, user_id: @user_id)
  prev = Folder.where(name: @folders[count], user_id: @user_id)

  for z in 0..last.count
    for x in 0..prev.count

      valid = Folder.exists?(name: last[z].name, parent_id: prev[x].id)

      case valid
      when true

        @test += valid.to_s
        @ids << Folder.find_by(id: prev[x].id).id
        #@ids = @ids[0].id

      else
      end

    end
  end

  @test += 'MSG'

  rescue Exception => e
      @test = e.message
      valid = false
    else
    end
```

This is a portion of code, everything working fine except the code after loops which displays message @test += 'MSG'. There is an exception in rescue block, which says undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass but the method returns the id, so its working. What is the issue, please help? Why the code after two loops will not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop should be `0..(last.count-1)` and `0..(prev.count-1)`, to account for 0 index.

Or a more readable excluded end range (as suggested by Neil Slater)

`0...last.count`  and `0...prev.count`

**EDIT**

Lets say `last` has 3 items in it. Then looping through `0..3` will go through

```
last[0], last[1], last[2], last[3] #(4 items) Which will result in error
```

So instead, you should loop through `0..2` or `0...3` (three dots means exclude last num)

Comment: or `0...last.count` etc . . . this is what the excluded end Range is for IMO. Also, OP does not appear to need values of `z` or `x`, so could use `last.each` . . .

Comment: After this fix everything works fine. But i still dont get why i need to decrement index in loop..

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your iterators `x` and `z` get too large and reference empty array indexes. But your code does not actually need them, as you *only* use `x` and `z` to index into the separate arrays.

It is quite rare in Ruby to use `for` loops to iterate through an `Array`. The core `Array` class has many methods that give ways to iterate through and process lists of objects, and it is usually possible to find one that does more precisely what you want, simplifying your code and improving readability.

Your code could be re-written using `Array#each`:

```
  last = Folder.where(name: @folders.last, user_id: @user_id)
  prev = Folder.where(name: @folders[count], user_id: @user_id)

  last.each do |last_folder|
    prev.each do |prev_folder|

      valid = Folder.exists?(name: last_folder.name, parent_id: prev_folder.id)

      case valid
      when true

        @test += valid.to_s
        @ids << Folder.find_by(id: prev_folder.id).id

      else
      end

    end
  end

  @test += 'MSG'
  ... etc
```